# Git squashed merge with conflicts missing commit message content

Tags: windows, git, git-squash

When I do a `git merge --squash <source_branch>` that results in conflicts, the pre-defined commit message content from Git contains only the conflicts information but not the summary of the squashed commits.

```
λ git merge --squash <source_branch>
Auto-merging res/strings_us/c4d_strings.str
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in res/strings_us/c4d_strings.str
Auto-merging res/config.ini
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in res/config.ini
Auto-merging readme.md
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
λ # resolve conflicts ...
λ git add res
λ git commit
Conflicts:
  res/config.ini
  res/strings_us/c4d_strings.str

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch <branch_name>
# Changes to be committed:
# modified:   res/config.ini
# modified:   res/strings_us/c4d_strings.str
```

How can I get Git to also include the information about the commits that have been squashed? Usually Git will write "Squash of the following commits:" and then show the `git log` of the commits that have been put into the squashed commit.

Using git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1

Comment: You say that Git "usually" will write a certain comment for squashing.  Have you changed versions recently?  Also, would it be possible for you to use `git rebase` in interactive mode and squash there?